# When will Debian packages available to Electric be available to Fuerte

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working through the book "ROS by Example".

The book states:

"The latest version of Ubuntu is 12.04 (Precise) and the latest version of ROS is Fuerte. Many ROS users are still using Electric but Debian packages for Electric are not
available for Precise."

What is the projected date for this situation to change?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45149/when-will-debian-packages-available-to-electric-be-available-to-fuerte/) by [TurtleBot_Fan](https://answers.ros.org/users/702/turtlebot_fan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2012-10-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There will not be Electric debian packages created for Precise, it's not a supported platform.  See [REP 3](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-10-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1